# softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2 giving non trainable output

Tags: tensorflow

tf version 2.1.0

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior() 


W = tf.Variable([0.5],tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([0.1],tf.float32)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y= tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
discounted_reward = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[4,], name="discounted_reward")
labels_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[4,], name="labels_")
linear_model = W*x + b

squared_delta = tf.square(linear_model - y)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(squared_delta,discounted_reward))
loss2 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits = y, labels = labels_))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(init)

for i in range(1):
    sess.run(train,{x:[1,2,3,4],y:[0,-1,-2,-3],labels_:[1,2,3,4],discounted_reward:[1,2,3,4]})

print(sess.run([W,b]))
sess.close()
```

I do have above code in which we have 2 loss

1. loss
2. loss2

When I use loss in optimizer (`train = optimizer.minimize(loss)`) then it run fine. 

But when i use loss2 in optimizer (`train = optimizer.minimize(loss2)`) it through error.

```
> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph
> for ops that do not support gradients, between variables
> ["<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_1:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_2:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_3:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_4:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>",
> "<tf.Variable 'Variable_5:0' shape=(1
```

I researched and got it is the issue with `tf.trainable_variables()` and i am sure `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2` is not giving trainable variable, But my code i need it. 
So any help ?

Comment: The error makes sense. Your `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2` takes two placeholders as inputs.  There's nothing to compute gradients w.r.t.

Comment: @thushv89 Hey. I am new in tensorflow can you tell how you can see that it have nothing to compute with respect to gradients ?

Comment: @thushv89 how can i solve ?

Comment: `y` needs to be something like the output of a neural network. Which takes some input `x` (of type `tf.placeholder`) and then compute `y` using several hidden layer computations (consisting of weights - type `tf.variable`). Unless you have `tf.variable` involved in your computation of `y`, there won't be a gradient.

Comment: @thushv89 you can post this as ans and then i will upvote.